# How to use join to combine two query into one?

Tags: sql

How to combine this two query to one? First I select `id` from `doorbots`

```
select id --> 2576673
from doorbots 
where device_id = '38d269cf5d1f';
```

Then I using this `id` to select `id` from `dings` table

```
select id 
from dings 
where doorbot_id = 2576673 and deleted_at is NULL;
```

How to combine this two query to one?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: You can combine them in many ways. E.g. with UNION, if you need one SELECT to get both IDs.

Comment: Could you say what you've tried please? This feels like the sort of problem you ought to be able to solve yourself. I'm sure there are hundreds of results out there if you just use Google. You're asking something that is really basic and fundamental to sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `in` statement you can ask for that specific id which you want.

Try this:-

```
select id 
from dings 
where doorbot_id in (select id 
from doorbots 
where device_id = '38d269cf5d1f')and deleted_at is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine it by using left join or join if both tables have relationship like

```
SELECT d.id 
FROM dings d 
LEFT JOIN doorbots ON dbs dbs.id = d.doorbot_id 
WHERE d.deleted_at IS NULL AND dbs.device_id = '38d269cf5d1f';

SELECT d.id 
    FROM dings d 
    JOIN doorbots ON dbs dbs.id = d.doorbot_id 
    WHERE d.deleted_at IS NULL AND dbs.device_id = '38d269cf5d1f';
```

or like this

```
SELECT id 
FROM dings 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM doorbots 
    WHERE device_id = '38d269cf5d1f'
) AND d.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace the "2576673" in your second query by your first query, surrounded by parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the same result in tree ways but still in a single query using **IN, EXISTS** and **JOIN**.

USING IN:

```
SELECT id
FROM dings
WHERE doorbot_id IN
  (SELECT id
  FROM doorbots
  WHERE device_id = '38d269cf5d1f')
AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

USING EXISTS:

```
SELECT id
FROM dings
WHERE doorbot_id EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM doorbots
  WHERE dings.doorbot_id =id and device_id = '38d269cf5d1f')
AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

USING JOIN:

```
SELECT dings.id
FROM doorbots
JOIN dings
ON doorbots.id = dings.doorbot_id
WHERE doorbots.device_id = '38d269cf5d1f'
AND dings.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in many ways. Using `JOIN`, `EXISTS` or `IN`. Both `EXISTS` and `IN` uses subquery.So I would suggest you go for `JOIN`. You can do something like:

```
SELECT d.id
FROM dings d
INNER JOIN doorbots db ON d.doorbot_id=db.id
WHERE db.device_id='38d269cf5d1f' AND d.deleted_at IS NULL
```